# IntelliJ How do I get rid of the vertical solid tab space block on the left side of the editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, indentation

I recently installed IntelliJ on a new Windows machine, and the editor comes with these distracting, vertical, solid blocks that represent tab spaces for indentation. I'm using IntelliJ 2023.1.2 Community Edition.
I would like to get rid of these lines. They are on the left side of the editor page as shown in the picture:

[image]

So far I have tried:
File > Settings > Editor > Color Schemes > Language Defaults
then also:
File > Settings > Editor > Color Schemes > Java
I also checked:
File > Settings > Editor > Code Styles > Java > Use Tab Character...
I selected and unselected this, and it made no difference.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed [Indent Rainbow](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13308-indent-rainbow) third-party plug-in which does this. [Disable the plug-in](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#disable-plugin).

[image: Indent Rainbow]